# What variable types to change after removing compiler option /J

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019

I'm migrating a MFC C++ project from VS2010 to VS2019. The project compiles with `/J` ([Default char Type Is unsigned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/j-default-char-type-is-unsigned)) and would love to get rid of the compiler option.

I know that I have to change `char` to `unsigned char` and I already wrote [clang-tidy](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/index.html) checker to do it.

Are there any other variable types I should change? And if yes, to which type?

Are there other things I maybe forgetting?

Or is the best solution to defining `_ATL_ALLOW_UNSIGNED_CHAR` as mentioned in [When will _ATL_ALLOW_UNSIGNED_CHAR work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27246149/1157147)? Just keep the compiler option.

Comment: According to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/j-default-char-type-is-unsigned?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019), if you use /J compiler option with ATL/MFC, an error might be generated. Although you could disable this error by defining _ATL_ALLOW_CHAR_UNSIGNED, this workaround is not supported and may not always work.
So I suggest you could set this in Property Pages->C/C++->Command Line->Additional Options pane. Remove it and rebuild all. As far as I'm concerned you couldn't need to change other variable types.

Comment: *"the `char` type is zero-extended when it is widened to an `int` type."* - This is the behavior you are about to change, and you need to account for **all** cases, where this makes a difference. Just renaming types won't do; you'd also have to change the type of *expressions*, including those that are not explicitly typed (e.g. `'\xFF'`). I'm not familiar with clang tools, but I'd start by writing an analyzer that dumps all places in code, where a widening conversion from `char` is performed (this includes implicit type promotions in comparisons, for example).